# RX Observable - measure execution time (even when nested)

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm using my appended class to measure execution time of my observables. This works fine, as long as I don't measure nested observables...

**Working fine**

```
Observable<T> obs1 = ...;
Observable<T> obs2 = ...;

obs1
    .compose(RXMeasure.applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag1"))
    .subscribe();

obs2
    .compose(RXMeasure.applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag2"))
    .subscribe();
```

**Not working**

```
Observable<T> obs3 = ...;

Observable<T> obs = obs1
    .flatMap(resul1 -> obs2)
    .flatMap(result2 -> obs3)
    .subscribe();
```

This leads to the result, that all observables are subscribed to at the start and this means, the measurement is not correct anymore. Here I'm trying to execute the 3 observables sequentially...

**What I want**

I want an measure function that

- is not breaking the chain
- is measuring EXECUTION time of an observable (something like the time between start/end of observable instead of subscribe/terminate)

Any ideas?

**RXMeasure class**

```
public class RXMeasure
{
    private static boolean mEnabled = true;

    public static void setEnabled(boolean enabled)
    {
        mEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> applyMeasurement(Class clazz, String tag)
    {
        return observable -> measure(observable, clazz, tag);
    }

    public static <T> Observable<T> measure(Observable<T> observable, Class clazz, String tag)
    {
        if (!mEnabled)
            return observable;

        LongHolder start = new LongHolder(0);
        return observable
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> start.set(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .doOnTerminate(() -> L.d(clazz, "[" + tag + "] Duration: " + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() - start.get()) + "ms"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum... if you want to run the sequentially and they do not have any data dependencies, won't this work?

```
Observable.concatMap(
  obs1.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag1")),
  obs2.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag2")),
  obs3.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag3")),
).subscribe();
```

Otherwise, you need to better define the term "execution time", especially for an observable that may be subscribed multiple times.

Edit: it looks like a plain `concat` is a solution:

```
Observable<Observable<T>> obss = Observable.just(
  obs1.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag1")),
  obs2.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag2")),
  obs3.compose(applyMeasurement(T.class, "tag3")),
);

Observable.concat(obss).subscribe();
```

My understanding from the docs and the RxJava source code is that `concat` will subscribe after the previous Observable completes / gets unsibscribed.

Comment: `concatMap` does not result in sequential execution, only in sequential emission... Execution time is the time the observable "works" in the sense of how long it needs to do all the things between `onStart` and `onComplete`...

Comment: I understand what you're saying as the time that an Observable "works" is the time taken from a "Producer.produce" to calling "Subscriber.onNext".

Comment: I've added my not so beautiful solution, sadly it's breaking the chain... That's why I don't like it...

Comment: I'll test that. I think I tried this already and concat was not subscribing sequentially but only emitting. But I know I had a bug with creating observables and not using defer for lists of data I loaded, maybe this was the problem and not the concat operator

Comment: I'm using `Observable.from(<list>)` instead of `Observable.just(<1 to 10 items>)`, but it seems to work now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have so far:

**Explanation**

I just force all my observables to be run sequential, not via chaining, but via a helper function...

**Code**

```
RXUtil.executeSequentially(
            observable -> {
                // subscribe the way you want
                observable.subscribe();
            },
            true,
            obs1,
            obs2,
            obs3);
}
```

**RXUtil class**

```
public class RXUtil 
{
    public static Observable executeSequentially(ISubscribe subscribe, boolean startObserving, Observable... observables)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observables.length - 1; i++)
        {
            final int fI = i;
            Observable observable = observables[i]
                    .doOnCompleted(new Action0() {
                        @Override
                        public void call() {
                            subscribe.subscribe(observables[(fI + 1)]);
                        }
                    });
            observables[i] = observable;
        }
        if (startObserving)
            subscribe.subscribe(observables[0]);
        return observables[0];
    }

    public interface ISubscribe<T>
    {
        void subscribe(Observable<T> observable);
    }
}
```